# The area of a hexagon determined by dropping perpendiculars from the midpoints of the sides of a triangle

Tags: geometry

[image]

> Let $H$, $D$, $F$ be midpoints of respective sides of acute (not-necessarily-equilateral) $\triangle ABC$. Prove that: 
>   $$\frac{\text{area of}\; \triangle ABC}{\text{area of}\; DEFGHI}=2$$

Comment: how is $S$ defined?

Comment: @TheSimpliFire . S=Area .

Comment: what Kind of triangle is given?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner .Triangle with acute angles .

Comment: Hint: Let $O$ be the orthocenter of the triangle. Prove that $E$, $G$, $I$ are the respective midpoints of $\overline{OA}$, $\overline{OB}$, $\overline{OC}$.

Answer (score 3):

In the figure, $O$ is the orthocenter, and $D$, $E$, $F$ are midpoints of respective sides of $\triangle ABC$.

[image]

Segments with matching tick marks are both parallel (by construction) and congruent (by deduction: think "midsegment"), so that the result follows (by dissection). $\square$

Comment: Why $AP=OP ,RC=OR ,BQ=OQ$

Comment: Midsegments! Midsegments everywhere! :)